# How to calculate uptime percentage of device using Flux query?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Given influxdb stream of device status with field "online" taking values true/false, how can I calculate uptime percentage of device in given time period?

I'm using Influxdb cloud with flux version: v0.194.5

Currently, I have this query with sample output below.

**Query**:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

from(bucket: "my-bucket")
|> range(start: -1d)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "device.status")
|> schema.fieldsAsCols()
|> stateDuration(unit: 1m, fn: (r) => r.online == true)
|> keep(columns: ["_time", "stateDuration", "online"])
```

**Result**:

```
"_time","online","stateDuration"
2023-12-02 15:19:29,true,0
2023-12-02 15:24:46,true,5
2023-12-02 15:29:59,true,10
2023-12-02 15:34:59,true,15
2023-12-02 15:40:26,true,20
2023-12-02 15:45:38,true,26
2023-12-02 15:50:38,true,31
2023-12-02 15:55:48,true,36
2023-12-02 16:00:57,true,41
2023-12-02 16:06:07,true,46
2023-12-02 16:11:07,true,51
2023-12-02 16:16:31,true,57
2023-12-02 16:21:41,true,62
2023-12-02 16:26:41,true,67
2023-12-02 16:31:44,true,72
2023-12-02 16:36:53,true,77
2023-12-02 16:41:53,true,82
2023-12-02 16:46:58,true,87
2023-12-02 16:52:08,true,92
2023-12-02 16:57:18,true,97
2023-12-03 17:02:50,false,-1
2023-12-03 17:12:58,false,-1
2023-12-03 17:22:01,false,-1
```

I want to sum all peak values which correspond to state change from online to offline. Sum is 97 in the above example. And uptime percentage = 97 / 122 = 0.795 = 79.5 %

**Remark**: Data points come at different intervals for true/false status